# $n$ is a positive prime number if only if $k^{n-1} \equiv 1$ mod $n$ with $1 < k < n$?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

When I read [the Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) I found a problem, after that I found the problem is [the Chinese hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_hypothesis).

When I read [the Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) I found that $(p-2)! \equiv -1 $ mod $p$ but after that I known this is special case of [the Sylow theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

I can not prove, can not check by my computer the following statement because the [Chinese hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_hypothesis) true up to $n={340}$ with $k$ is constant $2$. In here I let $1< k < n$

> > *Is it true that if $n$ is a positive prime number if only if $k^{n-1} \equiv 1$ mod $n$ with for all $k$, $1 < k < n$*

- If $n$ is positive prime number, by [the Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $\Rightarrow$ $k^{n-1} \equiv 1$ mod $n$.
- If $k^{n-1} \equiv 1$ mod $n$ with $k=1, 2, 3, ...,n-1$ then $n$ is also prime.

> > Or can you help me show that that why if $k^{n-1} \equiv 1$ mod $n$ then $gcd(k,n)=1$ ?

**See also:**

- [Agoh–Giuga conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem shows that if $n$ is a prime number, then $k^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for all $1 \le k \lt n$. The converse is also true. To show this, consider $n \gt 1$ not being prime, i.e., $n = ab$ where $a,b$ are positive integers with $1 \lt a,b \lt n$. Then $a^{k-1} \not\equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $b^{k-1} \not\equiv \pmod n$ since $a^{k-1} - 1$ and $b^{k-1} - 1$ must be relatively prime to $a$ and $b$ respectively and, thus, can't be a multiple of $n$. As such, if for some $n \gt 1$ you have $k^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ for all $1 \le k \lt n$, then $n$ must a prime.

This basically shows the last part you're asking about, i.e., if $k^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, then consider $\gcd(k,n) = d$. Since $d \mid n$ and $n \mid k^{n-1} - 1$, then $d \mid k^{n-1} - 1$, but for $n \gt 1$ this can only be true for $d = 1$.

Comment: I am sorry but why $n \mid k^{n-1} - 1$, then $d \mid k^{n-1} - 1$, but for $n \gt 1$ this can only be true for $d = 1$ ?

Comment: @ĐàoThanhOai Since $d = \gcd(k,n)$ then $d \mid k$. For $n \gt 1$, $k^{n-1}$ has at least one factor of $k$, so $d$ must divide $k^{n-1}$. As $d \mid k^{n-1} - 1$, then $d \mid 1$ also, which is only true for $d = 1$. Note for $n = 1$, then $k^{n-1} - 1 = k^0 - 1 = 1 -1 = 0$, so anything will divide into it, which is why I specifically say $n \gt 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n=pq$ is not a prime, and $p$ is a prime factor. Then $p^{n-1}$ has $p$ as a prime factor and can't be $\equiv 1 \bmod n$.

You may be interested in [Carmichael Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) which do have he property for all $k$ which are coprime with $n$ (eg $561$)

Comment: I am sorry, is the statement true or false?

Comment: I am using $p$ as an example to show that in $n$ is not prime the congruence doesn't hold. If $n$ is prime, it clearly does by Fermat. Hence if and only if. However $p$ as a counterexample is a rather trivial fail - no $q$ which has a non-trivial factor in common with $n$ can have $q^r\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for any integer $r\ge 1$. Carmichael Numbers are ones for which these are the only exceptions.